# Is there any way to convert unshared heap memory to shared memory? Primary target *nix

Tags: shared-memory

I was wondering whether there is any reasonably portable way to take existing, unshared heap memory and to convert it into shared memory.  The usage case is a block of memory which is too large for me to want to copy it unnecessarily (i.e. into a new shared memory segment) and which is allocated by routines out of my control.  The primary target is *nix/POSIX, but I would also be interested to know if it can be done on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [**mmap()**](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/mmap.html) with MAP_FIXED flag and address of your unshared memory (allocated from heap). However, if you provide **mmap()** with own pointer then it is constrained to be aligned and sized according to the size of memory page (may be requested by **sysconf()**) since mapping is only available for the whole page.

Comment: Re MAP_FIXED, I thought that that unmapped whatever was formerly in the map location, rather than sharing that memory.

Answer (score 0):

Many *nixe  have Plan-9's procfs which allows to open read a process's memory by inspecting /proc/{pid}/mem

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procfs

You tell the other process your pid, size and the base address and it can simply read the data (or mmap the region in its own address space)

**EDIT::** Apparently you can't open /proc/{pid}/mem without a prior ptrace(), so this is basically worthless.

---

Under most *nixes, `ptrace(2)` allows to attach to a process and read its memory.

---

The ptrace method does not work on OSX, you need more magic there:

- http://www.voidzone.org/readprocessmemory-and-writeprocessmemory-on-os-x/

---

What you need under Windows is the function `ReadProcessMemory`
.

---

Googling "What is ReadProcessMemory for $OSNAME" seems to return comprehensive result sets.

Comment: I was thinking of a more portable/less violent way than procps or ptrace, which are more debugging tools than IPC ones (and in particular, only one process can ptrace a given task at one time).  I assume I am out of luck with that.